# Decompose a Morlet wavelet in a sine wave to its gaussian and sine components

Tags: wavelet

I have a sine wave where there is a morlet wavelet inside:
[image: input signal]

Now, first I'd like to decompose my signal (func) to 2 components which are the sine wave and the wavelet.
After this, I'd like to decompose the wavelet to its gaussian and sine components.

I tried to do this with a continuous wavelet transform manually but I'm having troubles the recover the correct amplitudes of the wavelet and also with the logarithmic scale of the wavelet transform.

I also don't want to do this manually and would like to find an automatic way to extract those properties.

How is it possible to do this in another way?

I didn't try any sophisticated mathematics (which I don't know right now...)

I'm working with MATLAB.
So the code that creates the wavelet and the wavelet transform is:

```
clearvars;
close all;

j=sqrt(-1);
f_sys=50;                         
SR=1024;                             
cycles = 10;
Fs=SR*f_sys;

dt=1/(SR*f_sys);
eps=0.01; %half power bandwidth

miu2=0.15; % center move over t
f0=f_sys;

dF = 50;
fn = 0:dF:10e3;
wn = fn*2*pi;
t = 0:1/(SR*f_sys):(cycles/f_sys)-(1/(SR*f_sys));

for i=1:length(wn)
    phin = sqrt(1/0.0125)*(exp(-((t-miu2)/(eps)).^2));
    psin(i,:) = phin.*exp(j*wn(i).*(t-miu2));
end

sin2= 50.*exp(j*2*pi*f0*t);
sig=sin2;
wvlt = psin(8,:);
func = sig+wvlt;

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(real(sig))
title("sine wave");
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(real(wvlt))
title("wavelet");
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(real(func))
title("func = wavelet+sine");

plot_min_freq = 0;
plot_max_freq = 1000;

fb = cwtfilterbank('SignalLength',length(t),'SamplingFrequency',(SR*f_sys),'FrequencyLimits',[plot_min_freq plot_max_freq],'Wavelet','amor');
figure;
cwt(func,'FilterBank',fb);
[wt1,f]=cwt(func,'FilterBank',fb);
```

This is an example of a signal which I create but I'd like to do the same on a real signal.
The signal is composed of a sine wave at 50Hz and a morlet wavelet at 350Hz.

I thought about some first steps:

1. finding the 2D peaks in order to find the wavelet - I didn't succeed yet with the noise that I get from 50Hz and it is also possible that I'll get more than one wavelet in a specific time.
2. take a vector of the row where the peak of the wavelet is located - then I can see a kind of gaussian.
3. fit #2 to a gaussian.

Now I'm stuck and I don't believe that this is the correct way to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome here. Could you please share the code and results of what you already have so far? Thus, we can better spot the difficulties

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks!